# Get cell info from another column in the row

Tags: vba, excel

How do I make it so the email address for the recipient name is taken from a different column.

I have the names written out in a column and I want to check the date in the same row for each person and if its 1 month out then send an email to that person. I can only reference one specific cell but I need it for each row as it iterates down the P column.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim objDate As Date

For Each Cell In Range("P3:P4").Cells

    If Cell.Value <= Date + 30 Then

        'MsgBox "Going to expire in 1 month"

        Dim appOutlook As Outlook.Application
        Dim mitOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim recOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient

        ' Step 1: Initialize an Outlook session.
        Set appOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        ' Step 2: Create a new message.
        Set mitOutlookMsg = appOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With mitOutlookMsg
            ' Step3: Add the To recipient(s) to message.
            Set recOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(Cells(3, 2))
            recOutlookRecip.Type = olTo
            'Set valid properties like Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
            .Subject = "Test123"
            '.Body = "Test"
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .HTMLBody = " TEST EMAIL "        
            .Importance = olImportanceHigh 'High importance    
            ' Resolve every Recipient's name
            For Each recOutlookRecip In .Recipients
                recOutlookRecip.Resolve
                If Not recOutlookRecip.Resolve Then
                    mitOutlookMsg.Display
                End If
            Next
            .Send
        End With
        Set mitOutlookMsg = Nothing
        Set appOutlook = Nothing       

    Else

    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:
    Range.Offset(row, col)

For example:

```
 For Each Cell In Range("P3:P4").Cells
    'cell.Value refers to P3:P4
    myDate = cell.Value

    'cell.Offset(0, 1).Value refers to the column one to the right of cell
    myName = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
Next cell
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. If I do this:

myName = Cell.Offset(0, -9).Value
 MsgBox myName

it doesn't produce the names I have in the column. I checked I have the right offset number..its  9 columns to the left where the names are.

Comment: Offset is equivalent to pressing the arrow key that number of times. `ActiveSheet.Range("P1").Offset(0, -9).Select` will select G1.

Comment: I thought so too..but I can't get it to work for the life of me. If i put it in the cell to the right and put '1' it works..I put -9 in this one and I've tried other numbers and it won't return any value. See photo:

http://postimg.org/image/6yokm93wl/

Comment: Offset doesn't ignore hidden cells. Column G is 9 columns away from P. To get to column B, you'll need to use an offset of -14.

Comment: is it possible to skip certain columns or cells using a For Each Cell range loop?

Comment: For Each will got through every cell in the specified range. So, you can make a complicated range that only includes what you want, or you can have logic that tests to see if the cell is a specific value, row, etc, and take appropriate action.

Comment: I guess I could always have a separate for each block going through another set of cells.

How do I go about making a complicated range? It's to go through like 10 rows but then skip 1 then another 10 then skip 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58971/discussion-between-eric-harlan-and-ed-briscoe).